# How to make runBlocking wait for "all threads" in Unit Testing?

Tags: mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to write a unit test for `getUser()` function:

```
fun getUser(userId:Int) {
    // some code...

    launchDataOperation { api.getUser(userId) }
}
```

The issue I can see (but don't know how to resolve in a clean way) is  `launchDataOperation(...)` creates a coroutine to call suspend function `api.getUser`:

```
fun launchDataOperation(block: suspend () -> Unit): Job {
    return coroutineScope.launch {
        try {
            setLoading(true)
            block()
        } catch (error: NetworkConnectionException) {
            setError(Errors.NETWORK_CONNECTION_ERROR)
        } catch (error: DataOperationException) {
            setMessage(error.getErrors())
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my failing test:

```
@Test
fun `error message is displayed if api error occurred`() {
    val exception = DataOperationException(listOf("FATAL ERROR"))

    runBlocking {
        `when`(api.getUser(anyInt())).thenAnswer { throw exception }

        subject.getUser(userId)

        // execution fails if the below line is commented
        // this is not the correct way to wait for other coroutines
        delay(500)  // wait for 500ms till the other coroutines finish

        assertThat(subject.messages.value).isEqualTo(exception.getErrors())
    }
}
```

Comment: `launchDataOperation` returns a `Job`. You should wait for it to finish. It's not obvious in your code what would be the best place for it, but it could be either in `getUser`  or that could return the `Job`, and it's joined later.

Comment: Correct! But as you said, the application behavior does not need to wait for the job. I don't like the idea of tweaking app code for unit testing.
Do you recommend a better way re-structure the code?

Comment: It looks like this PR "https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/890" will resolve my issue.
Will confirm once it is released.